# Not passing JSON data from reducer to component correctly in Redux

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

So, following little example from redux official site about async actions (https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api), I decided to try this with my own example, but I get empty array every time in render part of the code, and in action when I console.log json array I get data that I wanted. I am new in redux so every new advice would help me out a lot.

[SOLUTION WAS THAT I DIDN'T FOLLOWED THE CORRECT PRINCIPLES USING REDUX AND ANSWER BELLOW IS THE CORRECT ANSWER]

Comment: Where is `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: You are right it is missing from the example in the link even though its working fine there, I followed example bellow from @Thananjaya and it worked well! :) So that is the answer to my question... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly, use redux-thunk. Redux Thunk is a middleware which allows you to write actions, return functions instead of actions. Go through this [documentation](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for the better understanding of redux-thunk.

From your code snippets, You have missed `mapDispatchToProps`. You are dispatching your actions in action creators, but you are not calling it in  `App.js`. Kindly, go through this [example app](https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react) that revolves using `fetch call` in actions.

Comment: This solution works great I have refactored my code using that article! Thanks a lot! :)